# How to add spaces after commas in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Suppose I have this csv file:

```
angDist,153.3115583,-52.5149861,  
0.155521,154.3621042,-53.9073389,  
6.447597,154.3621042,-53.9073389,  
0.062838,154.6195875,-31.8341278,
```

How can I change it to this format on notepad++, i.e, adding spaces after each comma:

```
angDist,   153.3115583,  -52.5149861,  
0.155521,  154.3621042,  -53.9073389,  
6.447597,  154.3621042,  -53.9073389, 
0.062838,  154.6195875,  -31.8341278,
```

Suppose I want to insert a number n of spaces.

Comment: Use Find and Replace. Search for `,`, replace with `, `. Add as many spaces as you want after the comma in the replace string.

Comment: Also, maybe `,\t` would work if you're trying to align the columns.

Comment: @bobquack, I was about to ask that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to replace a `,` with `,`  . However, if you have lines like `angDist,153.3115583,-52.5149861,` and you just replace "`,`" with "`,`  ", you will also add 2 spaces after the trailing `,`.

I suggest using a regular expression that would match *any comma not at the end of line*:

**Find What**:      `,(?!$)` (or `,(?!\h*$)`)
**Replace With**: `,`

Note: the `,(?!\h*$)` pattern matches any comma (`,`) that is not followed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces (`\h*`) at the end of the line (`$`). The `(?!...)` construct is called a [*negative lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that tries to match a pattern immediately to the right of the current location, and if the lookahead pattern matches, the whole match is failed. If `\h*` is omitted, the comma will get replaced with a comma and 2 spaces if there are spaces before the end of the line.

[image]